# connecting to blazor signalr from android device in cellular network

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

**Title:**
Timeout issue connecting to Blazor SignalR server from cellular network.

**Description:**
I'm facing an issue where my .NET MAUI Android client cannot connect to a Blazor SignalR server using a public IP address when on a cellular network. The application works fine with a local IP address. I've tried port forwarding on my router, but I'm experiencing a timeout error connection.

**Client-side Code:**

```cs
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://MyIpAddress:5011/formhub")
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
.// Your server-side code here
// Server side code
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
// Gerald: Enable SignalR functionality
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

builder.Services.AddTransient<UpdateFormService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITextService, TextGenerator>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<FormHub>("/formhub");
});

app.Run();
'''
I will appreciate any help
```

Comment: I already use it in AndroidManifest
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), the Android platform does not allow plaintext (HTTP) traffic by default, requiring apps to use HTTPS to secure data transmission.

So we need to set the `usesCleartextTraffic` option to allow http traffic. Like below.

```
//#if DEBUG                                   
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]  
//#else                                       
//[Application]                               
//#endif
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    ...
}
```

You may find I comment some attributes about `IF DEBUG`, in production,using `https` is the best solution, and we can use `[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]` for testing.